# Extract specific keys from variedly nested hash

Tags: ruby, recursion, hash, nested, extract

I'm trying to concatenate the different "Name" values from the provided Hash into one string. So the output should be one array or string containing all "Name" values.

The difficulty for me sits in that the **level of nesting varies between two and four parents.**

I've tried to solve it in two ways:

1. Recursively go through the hash and on each level append the value to an array. Finally spit out the array.
2. Flatten the hash and then cherry pick from that array

Unfortunately none of the answers given in related questions seemed to work either. I'm sure it's quite simple but I can't seem to figure it out. Many thanks

```
my_hash = { "BreadCrumbs" => {
                    "Id" => 375,
                    "Name" => "Willingen",
                    "Parent" => {
                        "Id" => 52272,
                        "Name" => "Wintersport-Arena Sauerland",
                        "Parent" => {
                            "Id" => 8, 
                            "Name" => "Germany"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: What output do you want?

Comment: one string containing all "Name" values

Comment: Glenn, please respond to @pangpang's question by editing your answer to show the string you want to obtain. (Are you sure you don't want an array?). Also, make your input a valid Ruby object (e.g, a hash with the single key-value pair you've shown) and assign it to a variable so that readers can reference the variable (e.g, `my_hash = { "BreakCrumbs => {...} }`. Lastly, you said ...it needs to be a recursive method". Are you sure about that?  More generally, you'll get more and better answers if you just say want you want to achieve, without reference to the approach you think is needed.

Comment: You need to edit your question even though it has already been answered to your satisfaction, as it may be read by many others in future.

Comment: Architecture and coding are both creative endeavours (and both include the mundane and minutiae). Lucky you. Do both!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
▶ hash = { "BreadCrumbs" => {
▷     "Id" => 375,        
▷     "Name" => "Willingen",        
▷     "Parent" => {        
▷       "Id" => 52272,            
▷       "Name" => "Wintersport-Arena Sauerland",            
▷       "Parent" => {            
▷         "Id" => 8,                 
▷         "Name" => "Germany"                
▷       }              
▷     }          
▷ }} 
▶ def concat hash
▷   [hash['Name'], hash['Parent'] ? concat(hash['Parent']) : nil]
▷ end  
▶ (concat hash['BreadCrumbs']).flatten.compact
#⇒ ["Willingen", "Wintersport-Arena Sauerland", "Germany"]
```

I do not flatten on every iteration so that the result still contains hierarchy:

```
▶ concat hash['BreadCrumbs']
#⇒ ["Willingen", ["Wintersport-Arena Sauerland", ["Germany", nil]]]
```

The requested string as the result:

```
▶ (concat hash['BreadCrumbs']).flatten.compact.join ', '
#⇒ "Willingen, Wintersport-Arena Sauerland, Germany"
```

Answer (score 0):

For any number of levels, without using recursion:

```
def pull_names(hash)
  h = hash
  names = []
  loop do
    names << h["Name"]
    return names unless h.key?("Parent")
    h = h["Parent"]
  end
end
```

Suppose:

```
hash = { "BreadCrumbs" => {
           "Name" => "Willingen",        
           "Parent" => {        
             "Id" => 52272,            
             "Name" => "Wintersport-Arena Sauerland",            
             "Parent" => {            
               "Id" => 8,                 
               "Name" => "Germany",
               "Parent" => {            
                 "Id" => 1,                 
                 "Name" => "Bora Bora"
               }              
             }          
           }
         }
       }
```

then:

```
arr = pull_names hash["BreadCrumbs"]
  #=> ["Willingen", "Wintersport-Arena Sauerland", "Germany", "Bora Bora"] 
arr.join(' ')
  #=> "Willingen Wintersport-Arena Sauerland Germany Bora Bora"
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond, very understandable answer (and the original post is adjusted too).